# sympy.solve() finds solutions only when replacing symbolic coefficients with Rational()

Tags: performance, sympy, symbols

I have a set of 3 Polynomial equations, (Basically representing a particular case of Apollonio's problem: given 3 circles of known positions and radius, find a a fourth one tangent to the other 3).
I have successfully used sympy to create the system and solve the equations for , say, x_4, y_4,r_4.
I obtain a solution quickly If I solve for a particular case, replacing the data of the 3 circles (9 parameters) with exact values, eg sympy.Rational(aNumber).
I tried instead to obtain a general solution expressed in terms of named parameters representing the 3 circle coordinates and radius, but sympy does not seem able to find a solution, even after one hour.
I have read that using symbols is slow, but I am not using direct numbers, I am using sp.Rational()
for all the coordinates.
From what I understand the Rational are not transormed to float. Also in my circles
there are no 0-coordinates that could lead to termi simplification and the general or specific equation do not seem  different.
Could anybody explain?

```
import sympy as sp
#complete running example
x ,y ,x_1,y_1,r_1,x_2,y_2,r_2,x_3,y_3,r_3,x_4,y_4,r_4 = sp.symbols('x  y  x_1 y_1 r_1 x_2 y_2 r_2 x_3 y_3 r_3 x_4 y_4 r_4')
class Cerchio:
    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r
        
class Soluzione:
    def crea_eq(self, x_i, y_i, r_i):
        expr = (x - x_i) ** 2 + (y - y_i) ** 2  - r_i ** 2
        posx = x_i + r_i * ((x_4 - x_i) / (r_4 + r_i))
        posy = y_i + r_i * ((y_4 - y_i) / (r_4 + r_i))
        val = expr.subs(x, posx).subs(y, posy)
        return val

    def __init__(self):
        self.finale1 = self.crea_eq(x_1, y_1, r_1)
        self.finale2 = self.crea_eq(x_2, y_2, r_2)
        self.finale3 = self.crea_eq(x_3, y_3, r_3)

    def find(self, c1, c2, c3, symbolic) -> object:
        if symbolic:  # seems to run forever
            sol = sp.solve((self.finale1, self.finale2, self.finale3), (x_4, y_4, r_4), set=True)
        else:   # fast
            qua1 = sp.Eq(self.replace(self.finale1, c1, c2, c3), 0)
            qua2 = sp.Eq(self.replace(self.finale2, c1, c2, c3), 0)
            qua3 = sp.Eq(self.replace(self.finale3, c1, c2, c3), 0)
            sol = sp.solve((qua1,qua2,qua3),(x_4,y_4,r_4),set=True)
        print(sol, '\nend of equation solution')

    def replace(self, esp, c1, c2, c3):
        return esp.subs(r_1, c1.r).subs(r_2, c2.r).subs(r_3, c3.r) \
                    .subs(x_1, c1.x).subs(y_1, c1.y).subs(x_2, c2.x) \
                    .subs(y_2, c2.y).subs(x_3, c3.x).subs(y_3, c3.y)

soluzione = Soluzione()
c4 = soluzione.find(Cerchio(sp.Rational(2), sp.Rational(2), sp.Rational(2)),
                    Cerchio(sp.Rational(5), sp.Rational(5), sp.Rational(2)),
                    Cerchio(sp.Rational(12), sp.sqrt(3), sp.Rational(2)), symbolic = False)
c4 = soluzione.find(Cerchio(sp.Rational(2), sp.Rational(2), sp.Rational(2)),
                    Cerchio(sp.Rational(5), sp.Rational(5), sp.Rational(2)),
                    Cerchio(sp.Rational(12), sp.sqrt(3), sp.Rational(2)), symbolic = True)
```

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily complicated making it difficult to see what the equations are that are actually being solved. Please simplify the code so that it just sets up the equations directly.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution that you seek is going to be too complicated to really be useful. After transforming your equations to a system of polynomials `solve` will try to solve these equations:

```
In [42]: polys = [Poly(r_1**2*x_4**2 - 2*r_1**2*x_1*x_4 + r_1**2*y_4**2 - 2*r_1**2*y_1*y_4 - r_1**2*r
    ...: _4**2 - 2*r_1**3*r_4 - r_1**4 + r_1**2*x_1**2 + r_1**2*y_1**2, x_4, y_4, r_4, domain='ZZ[r_1
    ...: ,x_1,y_1]'), Poly(r_2**2*x_4**2 - 2*r_2**2*x_2*x_4 + r_2**2*y_4**2 - 2*r_2**2*y_2*y_4 - r_2*
    ...: *2*r_4**2 - 2*r_2**3*r_4 - r_2**4 + r_2**2*x_2**2 + r_2**2*y_2**2, x_4, y_4, r_4, domain='ZZ
    ...: [r_2,x_2,y_2]'), Poly(r_3**2*x_4**2 - 2*r_3**2*x_3*x_4 + r_3**2*y_4**2 - 2*r_3**2*y_3*y_4 -
    ...: r_3**2*r_4**2 - 2*r_3**3*r_4 - r_3**4 + r_3**2*x_3**2 + r_3**2*y_3**2, x_4, y_4, r_4, domain
    ...: ='ZZ[r_3,x_3,y_3]')]

In [43]: eqs = [p.as_expr() for p in polys]

In [44]: eqs[0]
Out[44]: 
    4       3        2   2     2   2       2           2   2     2   2       2           2   2
- r₁  - 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₄ - r₁ ⋅r₄  + r₁ ⋅x₁  - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₁⋅x₄ + r₁ ⋅x₄  + r₁ ⋅y₁  - 2⋅r₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₄ + r₁ ⋅y₄ 

In [45]: eqs[1]
Out[45]: 
    4       3        2   2     2   2       2           2   2     2   2       2           2   2
- r₂  - 2⋅r₂ ⋅r₄ - r₂ ⋅r₄  + r₂ ⋅x₂  - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₂⋅x₄ + r₂ ⋅x₄  + r₂ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅r₂ ⋅y₂⋅y₄ + r₂ ⋅y₄ 

In [46]: eqs[2]
Out[46]: 
    4       3        2   2     2   2       2           2   2     2   2       2           2   2
- r₃  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅r₄ - r₃ ⋅r₄  + r₃ ⋅x₃  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₃⋅x₄ + r₃ ⋅x₄  + r₃ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅y₃⋅y₄ + r₃ ⋅y₄ 

In [47]: syms = [x_4, y_4, r_4]
```

It might look like those are simple equations but that does not mean that their solutions are simple. Here is a method that can give you the solutions by computing a Groebner basis:

```
In [50]: gb = groebner(eqs, syms)

In [51]: gb[0]
Out[51]: 
  2        2        2        2        2        2                                                   
r₁ ⋅y₂ - r₁ ⋅y₃ - r₂ ⋅y₁ + r₂ ⋅y₃ + r₃ ⋅y₁ - r₃ ⋅y₂ + r₄⋅(2⋅r₁⋅y₂ - 2⋅r₁⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₂⋅y₁ + 2⋅r₂⋅y₃ + 2

                      2        2        2        2        2        2                               
⋅r₃⋅y₁ - 2⋅r₃⋅y₂) - x₁ ⋅y₂ + x₁ ⋅y₃ + x₂ ⋅y₁ - x₂ ⋅y₃ - x₃ ⋅y₁ + x₃ ⋅y₂ + x₄⋅(2⋅x₁⋅y₂ - 2⋅x₁⋅y₃ - 2

                                          2        2           2        2     2           2
⋅x₂⋅y₁ + 2⋅x₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₃⋅y₁ - 2⋅x₃⋅y₂) - y₁ ⋅y₂ + y₁ ⋅y₃ + y₁⋅y₂  - y₁⋅y₃  - y₂ ⋅y₃ + y₂⋅y₃ 

In [52]: gb[1]
Out[52]: 
    2        2        2        2        2        2                                                 
- r₁ ⋅x₂ + r₁ ⋅x₃ + r₂ ⋅x₁ - r₂ ⋅x₃ - r₃ ⋅x₁ + r₃ ⋅x₂ + r₄⋅(-2⋅r₁⋅x₂ + 2⋅r₁⋅x₃ + 2⋅r₂⋅x₁ - 2⋅r₂⋅x₃ 

                         2        2           2        2        2        2     2           2       
- 2⋅r₃⋅x₁ + 2⋅r₃⋅x₂) + x₁ ⋅x₂ - x₁ ⋅x₃ - x₁⋅x₂  + x₁⋅x₃  - x₁⋅y₂  + x₁⋅y₃  + x₂ ⋅x₃ - x₂⋅x₃  + x₂⋅y

 2        2        2        2                                                                 
₁  - x₂⋅y₃  - x₃⋅y₁  + x₃⋅y₂  + y₄⋅(2⋅x₁⋅y₂ - 2⋅x₁⋅y₃ - 2⋅x₂⋅y₁ + 2⋅x₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₃⋅y₁ - 2⋅x₃⋅y₂)

In [53]: gb[2]
Out[53]: 
  4   2       4           4   2     4   2       4           4   2       2   2             2   2    
r₁ ⋅x₂  - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ + r₁ ⋅x₃  + r₁ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅r₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + r₁ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₂ + 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅

         2   2             2   2   2       2   2             2   2             2   2             2 
x₃ + 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₂ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₂ ⋅x₃  - 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₂ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅

  2   2       2   2             2   2             2   2   2       2   2             2   2          
r₂ ⋅y₃  + 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₃ ⋅x₂  + 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₃ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ + 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 2

   2   2             2   2   2       2   2             2   2   2       2   2             2   2   2 
⋅r₁ ⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₃ ⋅y₂  + 2⋅r₁ ⋅r₃ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₁ ⋅x₂  + 4⋅r₁ ⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₁ ⋅x₃  

      2   2   2       2   2             2   2   2       2      3       2      2          2         
- 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₁ ⋅y₂  + 4⋅r₁ ⋅x₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₁ ⋅y₃  + 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₁⋅x₂  - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅x₃

2       2         2       2                   2         2       2      3       2         2       2 
  + 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₂  - 4⋅r₁ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₃  + 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₁⋅x₃  + 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂  - 4⋅r₁ ⋅

                  2         2       2   3          2   2   2       2   2   2       2   2           
x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₃  - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ + 4⋅r₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅x₃  - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₁  + 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 2⋅

  2   2             2   2             2      3       2         2       2                   2       
r₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃  + 4⋅r₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁  - 4⋅r₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 4⋅r₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅

            2         2       2                   2         2       2   2   2       2   2          
y₁⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₂  + 8⋅r₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₃  - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₁  + 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 2

   2   2             2   2             2   2   2       2   2             2   2   2       2      3  
⋅r₁ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂  + 4⋅r₁ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₃  + 2⋅r₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₂  -

     2      2          2         2       2      3       2   3          2   2   2       2      3    
 2⋅r₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₂⋅y₃  + 2⋅r₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₃  - 2⋅r₁ ⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₁ ⋅y₂ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅r₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃  + r

 4   2       4           4   2     4   2       4           4   2       2   2   2       2   2       
₂ ⋅x₁  - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₃ + r₂ ⋅x₃  + r₂ ⋅y₁  - 2⋅r₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ + r₂ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅r₂ ⋅r₃ ⋅x₁  + 2⋅r₂ ⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂ 

      2   2             2   2             2   2   2       2   2             2   2             2   2
+ 2⋅r₂ ⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₃ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅r₃ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅r₃ ⋅y₁  + 2⋅r₂ ⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 2⋅r₂ ⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅r₃ 

             2   3          2   3          2   2   2       2   2             2   2   2       2   2 
⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁ ⋅x₂ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁ ⋅x₃ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁ ⋅x₂  - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ + 4⋅r₂ ⋅x₁ ⋅x₃  + 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁ ⋅

            2   2             2   2   2       2   2             2      2          2         2      
y₁⋅y₂ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁ ⋅y₂  + 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅x₃  + 2⋅r

 2         2       2                   2         2       2      3       2         2       2        
₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁  - 4⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₃  - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₃  - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁  - 4⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y

           2                   2         2       2                   2         2       2   2   2   
₁⋅y₂ + 8⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂  - 4⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₃  - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₂ ⋅x₃  - 

    2   2   2       2   2             2   2   2       2      3       2         2       2           
2⋅r₂ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₁  + 4⋅r₂ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₃  + 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₂⋅x₃  + 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁  - 4⋅r₂ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y

        2         2       2   2             2   2             2   2   2       2   2             2  
₃ + 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₃  + 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₂  + 2⋅r₂ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅r₂ ⋅y

 3          2   3          2   2   2       2   2             2   2   2       2      2          2   
₁ ⋅y₂ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅r₂ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₂ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₃  + 4⋅r₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₂ ⋅y₁

      2       2      3       2   2   2       2      3     4   2       4           4   2     4   2  
⋅y₂⋅y₃  - 2⋅r₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃  - 2⋅r₂ ⋅y₂ ⋅y₃  + 2⋅r₂ ⋅y₂⋅y₃  + r₃ ⋅x₁  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂ + r₃ ⋅x₂  + r₃ ⋅y₁  -

     4           4   2       2   3          2   3          2   2   2       2   2             2   2 
 2⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + r₃ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁ ⋅x₂ + 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁ ⋅x₃ + 4⋅r₃ ⋅x₁ ⋅x₂  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁ ⋅

  2       2   2             2   2             2   2             2   2   2       2      3       2   
x₃  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁

   2          2         2       2         2       2                   2                   2        
⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ + 4⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅x₃  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁  + 8⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 4⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y

 2       2                   2         2       2         2       2                   2         2   
₂  - 4⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₃  + 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁  - 4⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂  + 

    2   3          2   2   2       2   2             2   2             2   2             2   2   2 
2⋅r₃ ⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₂ ⋅x₃  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₃  

      2         2       2                   2         2       2   2   2       2   2             2  
+ 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁  - 4⋅r₃ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₂  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₁  + 4⋅r₃ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 2⋅r₃ ⋅x

 2   2       2   3          2   3          2   2   2       2   2             2   2   2       2     
₃ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂ + 2⋅r₃ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₃ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₃ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y

 3       2      2          2         2       2   3          2   2   2     2 ⎛    2   2       2     
₂  - 2⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂⋅y₃  + 2⋅r₃ ⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ - 2⋅r₃ ⋅y₂ ⋅y₃  + r₄ ⋅⎝4⋅r₁ ⋅x₂  - 8⋅r₁ ⋅x₂⋅x

        2   2       2   2       2             2   2                                                
₃ + 4⋅r₁ ⋅x₃  + 4⋅r₁ ⋅y₂  - 8⋅r₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₁ ⋅y₃  - 8⋅r₁⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₂ + 8⋅r₁⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₃ + 8⋅r₁⋅r₂⋅x₂⋅x₃

             2                                                             2                       
 - 8⋅r₁⋅r₂⋅x₃  - 8⋅r₁⋅r₂⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 8⋅r₁⋅r₂⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 8⋅r₁⋅r₂⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 8⋅r₁⋅r₂⋅y₃  + 8⋅r₁⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₂ - 8⋅r₁

                      2                                                             2              
⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₃ - 8⋅r₁⋅r₃⋅x₂  + 8⋅r₁⋅r₃⋅x₂⋅x₃ + 8⋅r₁⋅r₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 8⋅r₁⋅r₃⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 8⋅r₁⋅r₃⋅y₂  + 8⋅r₁⋅r₃⋅y₂⋅

         2   2       2             2   2       2   2       2             2   2             2       
y₃ + 4⋅r₂ ⋅x₁  - 8⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₃ + 4⋅r₂ ⋅x₃  + 4⋅r₂ ⋅y₁  - 8⋅r₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₂ ⋅y₃  - 8⋅r₂⋅r₃⋅x₁  + 8⋅r₂

                                                      2                                            
⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₂ + 8⋅r₂⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₃ - 8⋅r₂⋅r₃⋅x₂⋅x₃ - 8⋅r₂⋅r₃⋅y₁  + 8⋅r₂⋅r₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 8⋅r₂⋅r₃⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 8⋅r₂⋅r₃⋅y

           2   2       2             2   2       2   2       2             2   2       2   2       
₂⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₃ ⋅x₁  - 8⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂ + 4⋅r₃ ⋅x₂  + 4⋅r₃ ⋅y₁  - 8⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅r₃ ⋅y₂  - 4⋅x₁ ⋅y₂  + 8⋅x₁

2             2   2                                                             2                  
 ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅x₁ ⋅y₃  + 8⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 8⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 8⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 8⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₃  - 8⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ +

                           2                       2   2       2             2   2             2   
 8⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 8⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂  - 8⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅x₂ ⋅y₁  + 8⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 4⋅x₂ ⋅y₃  + 8⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁  - 

                                                    2   2       2             2   2⎞      ⎛    3   
8⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 8⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 8⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅x₃ ⋅y₁  + 8⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 4⋅x₃ ⋅y₂ ⎠ + r₄⋅⎝4⋅r₁ ⋅x₂

2       3             3   2       3   2       3             3   2       2                2         
  - 8⋅r₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ + 4⋅r₁ ⋅x₃  + 4⋅r₁ ⋅y₂  - 8⋅r₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₁ ⋅y₃  - 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₂ + 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₃

       2                2      2       2                2                2                2      2 
 + 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₂⋅x₂⋅x₃ - 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₂⋅x₃  - 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₂⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₂⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₂⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₂⋅y₃  

      2                2                2      2       2                2                2         
+ 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₂ - 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₃ - 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₃⋅x₂  + 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₃⋅x₂⋅x₃ + 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₃⋅y₁⋅y₃

       2      2       2                   2                2                2                2   2 
 - 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₃⋅y₂  + 4⋅r₁ ⋅r₃⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₂ + 4⋅r₁⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₃ + 4⋅r₁⋅r₂ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅r₂ ⋅x₃  

         2                2                2                2   2          2                2      
- 4⋅r₁⋅r₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅r₁⋅r₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₁⋅r₂ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅r₂ ⋅y₃  + 4⋅r₁⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂ - 4⋅r₁⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₃

          2   2          2                2                2                2   2          2       
 - 4⋅r₁⋅r₃ ⋅x₂  + 4⋅r₁⋅r₃ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ + 4⋅r₁⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 4⋅r₁⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅r₃ ⋅y₂  + 4⋅r₁⋅r₃ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ 

         2   2          2                2   2          2   2          2                2   2      
- 4⋅r₁⋅x₁ ⋅x₂  + 8⋅r₁⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅x₁ ⋅x₃  - 4⋅r₁⋅x₁ ⋅y₂  + 8⋅r₁⋅x₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅x₁ ⋅y₃  + 4⋅r

       3             2                   2                2                                   2    
₁⋅x₁⋅x₂  - 4⋅r₁⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅x₃  + 4⋅r₁⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₂  - 8⋅r₁⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₁⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₃  + 4

         3                2                                   2          3             2   2       
⋅r₁⋅x₁⋅x₃  + 4⋅r₁⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂  - 8⋅r₁⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₁⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₃  - 4⋅r₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ + 8⋅r₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃  - 4⋅r₁

   2   2          2                2                2                   3                2         
⋅x₂ ⋅y₁  + 4⋅r₁⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅r₁⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅x₂ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅x₂⋅x₃  + 8⋅r₁⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁  - 8⋅r₁⋅x

                                             2                                    2          2   2 
₂⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 8⋅r₁⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₂  + 16⋅r₁⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₃  - 4⋅r₁⋅x₃ ⋅y₁  

         2                2                2                2   2          2                2   2  
+ 4⋅r₁⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅r₁⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅x₃ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅y₁ ⋅y₂  + 8⋅r₁⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅y₁ ⋅y₃  +

           3             2                   2             3          3             2   2          
 4⋅r₁⋅y₁⋅y₂  - 4⋅r₁⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₁⋅y₁⋅y₂⋅y₃  + 4⋅r₁⋅y₁⋅y₃  - 4⋅r₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ + 8⋅r₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃  - 4⋅r₁⋅y₂

   3       3   2       3             3   2       3   2       3             3   2       2      2    
⋅y₃  + 4⋅r₂ ⋅x₁  - 8⋅r₂ ⋅x₁⋅x₃ + 4⋅r₂ ⋅x₃  + 4⋅r₂ ⋅y₁  - 8⋅r₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₂ ⋅y₃  - 4⋅r₂ ⋅r₃⋅x₁  + 4

   2                2                2                2      2       2                2            
⋅r₂ ⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₂ + 4⋅r₂ ⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₃ - 4⋅r₂ ⋅r₃⋅x₂⋅x₃ - 4⋅r₂ ⋅r₃⋅y₁  + 4⋅r₂ ⋅r₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅r₂ ⋅r₃⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 

    2                   2   2          2                2                2                2   2    
4⋅r₂ ⋅r₃⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₂⋅r₃ ⋅x₁  + 4⋅r₂⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂ + 4⋅r₂⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₃ - 4⋅r₂⋅r₃ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ - 4⋅r₂⋅r₃ ⋅y₁  + 4

      2                2                2                3             3             2   2         
⋅r₂⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅r₂⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₂⋅r₃ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₂⋅x₁ ⋅x₂ - 4⋅r₂⋅x₁ ⋅x₃ - 4⋅r₂⋅x₁ ⋅x₂  - 4⋅r₂⋅x

 2                2   2          2                2                2   2          2                
₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ + 8⋅r₂⋅x₁ ⋅x₃  + 4⋅r₂⋅x₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 4⋅r₂⋅x₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₂⋅x₁ ⋅y₂  + 4⋅r₂⋅x₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 8⋅r₂⋅x₁

   2                   2                2                                   2             3        
⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ - 4⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅x₃  + 4⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁  - 8⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₃  - 4⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₃  - 4⋅r₂⋅

        2                                                       2                                  
x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁  - 8⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 16⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 8⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂  - 8⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y

 2          2   2          2   2          2                2   2             3                2    
₃  - 4⋅r₂⋅x₂ ⋅x₃  - 4⋅r₂⋅x₂ ⋅y₁  + 8⋅r₂⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₂⋅x₂ ⋅y₃  + 4⋅r₂⋅x₂⋅x₃  + 4⋅r₂⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁  - 8

                               2          2                2                2   2          2       
⋅r₂⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₂⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₃  + 4⋅r₂⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 4⋅r₂⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₂⋅x₃ ⋅y₂  + 4⋅r₂⋅x₃ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ 

         3             3             2   2          2                2   2             2           
+ 4⋅r₂⋅y₁ ⋅y₂ - 4⋅r₂⋅y₁ ⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₂⋅y₁ ⋅y₂  - 4⋅r₂⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 8⋅r₂⋅y₁ ⋅y₃  + 8⋅r₂⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₂⋅

        2             3          2   2             3       3   2       3             3   2       3 
y₁⋅y₂⋅y₃  - 4⋅r₂⋅y₁⋅y₃  - 4⋅r₂⋅y₂ ⋅y₃  + 4⋅r₂⋅y₂⋅y₃  + 4⋅r₃ ⋅x₁  - 8⋅r₃ ⋅x₁⋅x₂ + 4⋅r₃ ⋅x₂  + 4⋅r₃ ⋅

  2       3             3   2          3             3             2   2          2                
y₁  - 8⋅r₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅r₃ ⋅y₂  - 4⋅r₃⋅x₁ ⋅x₂ + 4⋅r₃⋅x₁ ⋅x₃ + 8⋅r₃⋅x₁ ⋅x₂  - 4⋅r₃⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ - 4⋅r₃⋅x₁

2   2          2                2                2                2   2             3             2
 ⋅x₃  - 4⋅r₃⋅x₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅r₃⋅x₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₃⋅x₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₃⋅x₁ ⋅y₃  - 4⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₂  - 4⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₂ 

                   2                2                                                       2      
⋅x₃ + 8⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅x₃  - 4⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁  + 16⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 8⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₂  - 8⋅r

                             2                2                                   2          3     
₃⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 8⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₃  + 4⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁  - 8⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂  + 4⋅r₃⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ -

        2   2          2                2                2                2   2                2   
 4⋅r₃⋅x₂ ⋅x₃  - 4⋅r₃⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅r₃⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 4⋅r₃⋅x₂ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₃⋅x₂ ⋅y₃  + 4⋅r₃⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁  - 

                                2          2   2          2                2   2          3        
8⋅r₃⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅r₃⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₂  - 4⋅r₃⋅x₃ ⋅y₁  + 8⋅r₃⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 4⋅r₃⋅x₃ ⋅y₂  - 4⋅r₃⋅y₁ ⋅y₂ + 4⋅

     3             2   2          2                2   2             3             2               
r₃⋅y₁ ⋅y₃ + 8⋅r₃⋅y₁ ⋅y₂  - 4⋅r₃⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₃⋅y₁ ⋅y₃  - 4⋅r₃⋅y₁⋅y₂  - 4⋅r₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ + 8⋅r₃⋅y₁⋅y

    2          3             2   2⎞     4   2       4           4   2     4   2       4           4
₂⋅y₃  + 4⋅r₃⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ - 4⋅r₃⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ ⎠ + x₁ ⋅x₂  - 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃ + x₁ ⋅x₃  + x₁ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅x₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + x₁ 

   2       3   3       3   2          3      2       3      2       3                3      2      
⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂  + 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ + 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃  - 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅y₂  + 4⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅y₃  - 2⋅x

 3   3       3      2       3                3      2     2   4       2   3          2   2   2     
₁ ⋅x₃  - 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₃⋅y₂  + 4⋅x₁ ⋅x₃⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₃⋅y₃  + x₁ ⋅x₂  + 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ - 6⋅x₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅x₃  + 2⋅

  2   2   2       2   2             2   2             2   2   2       2   2             2   2   2  
x₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₁  - 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂ ⋅y₃  +

     2      3       2         2       2                   2                   2         2       2  
 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃  - 4⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁  + 4⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₂  - 8⋅x₁ ⋅x

                 2         2     2   4       2   2   2       2   2             2   2             2 
₂⋅x₃⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₃  + x₁ ⋅x₃  + 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₁  - 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₁ ⋅

  2   2       2   2             2   2   2       2   2   2       2   2             2   2   2       2
x₃ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₁ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₃  + 2⋅x₁ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂  - 4⋅x₁ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₁ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₁ 

      3       2      2          2         2       2      3     2   4       2   3          2   2   2
⋅y₁⋅y₂  + 2⋅x₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₂⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₁ ⋅y₁⋅y₃  + x₁ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅x₁ ⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₁ ⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ 

       2      3     2   4          4             3   2          3   2          3                3  
 - 2⋅x₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃  + x₁ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ + 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅y₁  + 4⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅y

 2          2   3          2      2          2                   2                   2      2      
₃  + 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃  + 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃⋅y₁  + 4⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 8⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 4⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃⋅y₂  + 4⋅x

    2                   2      2             4             2   2             2                   2 
₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₁⋅x₂ ⋅x₃⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅x₃  + 2⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅x₃ ⋅y₁  - 8⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + 4⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅x₃ ⋅

                  2   2             2                   2   2             2   2             2      
y₁⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅x₃ ⋅y₂  + 4⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅x₃ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 4⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅x₃ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁ ⋅y₂  + 4⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃

             2   2                2                      2                3             2   2      
 - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁ ⋅y₃  + 4⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ - 8⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁⋅y₂⋅y₃  + 4⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₁⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₂ ⋅y₃  + 4⋅x

          3             4          3   2          3                3   2             2   2         
₁⋅x₂⋅y₂⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₂⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₃ ⋅y₁  + 4⋅x₁⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 2⋅x₁⋅x₃ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁ ⋅y₂  + 4⋅x₁⋅x

    2                   2   2                3                2                      2             
₃⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁ ⋅y₃  + 4⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂  - 8⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ + 4⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂

4             3                2   2     4   2     4   2       4           4   2       3   3       
  + 4⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ - 2⋅x₁⋅x₃⋅y₂ ⋅y₃  + x₂ ⋅x₃  + x₂ ⋅y₁  - 2⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃ + x₂ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₂ ⋅x₃  - 2⋅x₂

3      2       3                3      2     2   4       2   2   2       2   2             2   2   
 ⋅x₃⋅y₁  + 4⋅x₂ ⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₃ - 2⋅x₂ ⋅x₃⋅y₃  + x₂ ⋅x₃  + 2⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₁  - 2⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 2⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₁

          2   2   2       2   2             2   2   2     2   4       2   3          2   3         
⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₂ ⋅x₃ ⋅y₃  + x₂ ⋅y₁  - 2⋅x₂ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂ - 2⋅x₂ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₃ + 2⋅x

 2   2   2       2   2             2   2   2       2      2          2         2       2      3    
₂ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂  + 2⋅x₂ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₂ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₃  - 4⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₂⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₂ ⋅y₁⋅y₃  + 2

   2   2   2       2      3     2   4          3   2          3                3   2             4 
⋅x₂ ⋅y₂ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₂ ⋅y₂⋅y₃  + x₂ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₂⋅x₃ ⋅y₁  + 4⋅x₂⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ - 2⋅x₂⋅x₃ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁  

            3                3                2   2             2                   2   2          
+ 4⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁ ⋅y₂ + 4⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁ ⋅y₃ - 2⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁ ⋅y₂  - 8⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ - 2⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁ ⋅y₃  + 4⋅x₂⋅x₃

      2                      2             2   2     4   2       4           4   2     2   4       
⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ + 4⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₁⋅y₂⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₂⋅x₃⋅y₂ ⋅y₃  + x₃ ⋅y₁  - 2⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂ + x₃ ⋅y₂  + x₃ ⋅y₁  - 2⋅x₃

2   3          2   3          2   2   2       2   2             2   2   2       2      3       2   
 ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂ - 2⋅x₃ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₃ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂  + 2⋅x₃ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₃ ⋅y₁ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂  + 2⋅x₃ ⋅y₁

   2          2         2     2   4       2   3          2   2   2     4   2       4           4   
⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ - 4⋅x₃ ⋅y₁⋅y₂⋅y₃  + x₃ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅x₃ ⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ + 2⋅x₃ ⋅y₂ ⋅y₃  + y₁ ⋅y₂  - 2⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃ + y₁ ⋅y₃

2       3   3       3   2          3      2       3   3     2   4       2   3          2   2   2   
  - 2⋅y₁ ⋅y₂  + 2⋅y₁ ⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ + 2⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃  - 2⋅y₁ ⋅y₃  + y₁ ⋅y₂  + 2⋅y₁ ⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ - 6⋅y₁ ⋅y₂ ⋅y₃  + 

    2      3     2   4          4             3   2          2   3             4     4   2       3 
2⋅y₁ ⋅y₂⋅y₃  + y₁ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃ + 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃  + 2⋅y₁⋅y₂ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅y₁⋅y₂⋅y₃  + y₂ ⋅y₃  - 2⋅y₂ ⋅

  3     2   4
y₃  + y₂ ⋅y₃
```

Now the first two equations give `x_4` and `y_4` linearly in terms of `r_4`. The third equation is a quartic polynomial for `r_4`. There is a quartic formula so you can have the general solution if you want but the quartic formula is very complicated and this polynomial has complicated coefficients so the expression for the solutions will be extremely complicated. If you want to see it then you can do:

```
In [55]: sols = roots(gb[2], r_4, multiple=True)

In [56]: sols[0]
Out[56]: 
...
```

Here I won't show the output because it exceeds StackOverflow's limit on the number of characters that can be included in an answer but that output would show the expression for `r_4` in the first of the 4 solutions. To see the solution for `x_4` you would do:

```
In [59]: solve(gb[0], x_4)[0].subs(r_4, sols[0])
```

This is now an extremely complicated solution having an operation count of 10175:

```
In [59]: solve(gb[0], x_4)[0].subs(r_4, sols[0]).count_ops()
Out[59]: 10175
```

The bottom line here is that sometimes a general symbolic solution is too complicated to be useful.

Comment: I appreciate your knowledge and the proposed solutions. However I have still a doubt: Why using using sp.Rational() instead of sp.Symbols() for all the coefficients is so much faster? Any pointer to some doc explaining the inner working of sympy would be appreciated

Comment: It is faster because the numeric solution is a simple expression but the general symbolic solution is extremely complicated. Just look at the polynomials I showed above and go check out the quartic formula.